# Knockout.js: Custom binding resetting the value

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

In the following code the idea is that if you fill in 'test' that this is considered invalid and shouldn't write the value to the observable. The problem I have is that my custom binding is somehow resetting the observable's value.

A working version of the code below: http://jsfiddle.net/6hcpM/1/

```
var underlying = ko.observable('foo');
var errors = ko.observableArray()
var isValid = ko.dependentObservable(function(){
    return errors().length === 0
});

var vm = {
    name : ko.dependentObservable({
        read : underlying,
        write : function(value){
            errors([]);

            if(value==='test'){
             errors([ 'Cant be test matey' ]);   
            };

            if(isValid()){
              underlying(value);
            };
        }
    })
};

vm.name.isValid = isValid;

ko.bindingHandlers.validateCss = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
       observable = valueAccessor();
       observable.isValid(); //this somehow causes the problem
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `validateCss` binding creates a dependency to `vm.name.isValid`.  When you write "test" to the field, `errors` is updated, which causes `isValid` to update, which triggers all of the bindings in the input's `data-bind` attribute to be re-evaluated.  So, the `value` binding gets evaluated again and replaces the current value with the value from `name` (which is stored in `underlying`).

So, basically the `value` binding is running again based on `isValid` changing.

There are several ways that you could handle it.  You could let `underlying` get updated every time and, if necessary, store a clean value elsewhere that only gets updated when it is valid.

You could also put your custom binding on a different element.  For example, you could wrap your `input` in a span or div and put the binding on it.  I assume that you want the `validateCss` binding to assign a CSS class when the value is invalid.

Comment: Putting validateCss on a different element sounds like a good solution.